# ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to start an activity from my main activity. Its not working and driving me nuts.  What I have is:

```
Intent i = new Intent ("net.xxx.View1");  
Context con = this.getBaseContext();  
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("net.xxx.Mybooks", "BookView");  
i.setComponent(cn);  
Bundle extras = new Bundle();  
ooo             
i.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(i);
```

---

```
Manifest is:  
            android:name="BookView" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action   android:name ="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action   android:name ="net.xxx.View1" />       
            <category android:name ="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

What I get is:
    **02-03 19:34:47.448: E/AndroidRuntime(2027): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {net.xxx.Mybooks/BookView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml **
Which would be correct, I think, if the '/' was a '.'

I tried with context and without any componetName, the result is always the same.

SdkVersion="10"
Thanks in advance for your help
Cliff

Comment: I also tried    Intent i = new Intent (this, BookView.class); and I get "02-04 14:24:31.750: E/AndroidRuntime(480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.crl.mybooks/net.crl.mybooks.BookView}: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well despite the clams of activity not found, the problem was in the new activity.  It had a null pointer exception in the code.  So I spent a day or so chasing the wrong problem.

Thanks for your time anyway

Cliff

Answer (score 4):

Try putting a "." in front of BookView
Try doing something like this in your manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".BookView" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action   android:name ="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action   android:name ="net.xxx.View1" />       
        <category android:name ="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I tried that.  I get the same result, or one that has 'new.xxx.MyBooks/net.xxx...'   But thanks for the reply.    Cliff

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem after refactor my package name, and I finally found that my `applicationId` value in `build.gradle` has typo, and Android Studio doesn't give any warning.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after I renamed some activities. Make sure you update your AndroidManifest to reflect renaming changes.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this when I put Activity-derived class nested in another class, so it can not be found, moving outside solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity is defined in manifest. I had copy pasted a Activity class and forgotten to add the definition in manifest file and ended up with this problem.

Comment: Yes that would be a problem, but my problem was different.  See answer below.