# ActivityNotFoundException: unable to find explicit activity class . android.content.ClipData$Item missing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My logcat shows

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.storemanager/android.content.ClipData$Item}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

My intent is like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryMain.this, Item.class);
intent.putExtra("childData", childDataMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

Android Manifest is like

```
<activity android:name="CategoryMain" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Item" >
        </activity>
```

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137780/activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class) question, it is mentioned that it might be due to some nullpointer exception in the next activity, I tried to debug it but the debugger does not moves to the next activity.
Please tell me where I am wrong ?

**Edit**: I have already tried changing "Item" to ".Item"

**SOLVED:** after trying each and every method , finally I came to realize there was no problem with my android manifest . The problem was a `nullpointerexception`  in the `oncreate` method in the next activity.

Comment: try giving full path com.example.storemanager.CategoryMain

Comment: Are you sure that your `Item.java` is located in your package `com.example.storemanager`

Comment: yes Item.java is in the same package .

Comment: Try to clean your project and run it. And, tell me are you using any `.jar` external files? And, once try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12932814/940096) also

Comment: The first thing I tried was to clean my project. No external .jar files used!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<activity 
android:name=".CategoryMain" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Item" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: check your Item Activity may be the problem is in that activity

Comment: Indeed there was a nullpointer exception in my Item Activity. Thanks a lot . Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its a good habit to give the [Fully Qualified class Name](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

```
<activity 
   android:name="com.example.storemanager.CategoryMain" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.storemanager.Item" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: still getting 09-27 04:27:05.400: E/AndroidRuntime(2763): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.storemanager/android.content.ClipData$Item}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: are you using any external jars in your project

Comment: No ! I am not using any external jars.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908534/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-clas) link may help you.Check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
......
......
<activity android:name=".CategoryMain" />
<activity android:name=".Item" />
......
......
```

**Update**

Have you ever tried to declare your activity with full package?

```
<activity android:name="com.example.storemanager.Item />
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the above the answers are not working, I have a feeling that the name Item is a little fishy, since android use item tags. Try to change the activity name to ItemActivity.

 I am just guessing.